# How to exclude items from recyclerview which are existing in some Firestore Collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection `users` and showing all users in `RecyclerView`. I also have another collection named BLOCKED and having some users in this collection (actually blocked users are also available in `users` collection).

I want to exclude BLOCKED users in `RecyclerView`. I have no idea about the same.

I think for loop might work but I really don't know how to implement the same, as I am the basic / fresher developer.

Comment: just post what you tried,then only we will any suggestion

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far for us.

Comment: I added code for Recyclerview

Comment: So to understand better, you have two collections, users and bloked users and you want to display in your RecyclerView only the users that are not blocked, right? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir. I want it.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer for that.